# QML menu style only works in QtWidgets QApplication

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols, qapplication

I am running `Qt 5.11.0` under Windows *(I understand that it is very old but I cannot upgrade that embedded system)*.

For some reason, QML `Menu` from `QtQuickControls1` ignores its `style` if app is a `QGuiApplication`, but works if it is a `QApplication` (from QtWidgets).

I also noticed that `QApplication` uses `Desktop` style by default, whereas `QGuiApplication` uses `Base` style instead and cannot load `Desktop` style at all.

Is `QtWidgets` dependency required to load `QtQuickControls1` styles correctly, or am I missing something?

Why does `QApplication` change QML styling at all?

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtQml/qqmlapplicationengine.h>
#include <QtQml/qqmlcomponent.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
        //QGuiApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv); //works
        QGuiApplication* app = new QGuiApplication(argc, argv); //does not work
        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl("file:///C:/main.qml"));
        app->exec();
        delete app;
        return 0;
}
```

main.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
    
Window {
        visible: true
        Column{
            CheckBox { text: "checkbox"}
            ComboBox { model: ["combobox"] }
            Button { text: "button"}
            Button {
                text: "custom"
                menu: Menu {
                    style: MenuStyle { frame: Rectangle { color: "yellow" } }
                    MenuItem{text: "menuitem"}
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Expected results:

- Menu should have yellow background.

Actual results:

[image: qml test results]

Comment: Side note: When you say you are using "Qt 11.0", I assume you mean you are using 5.11.0.

Comment: I don't have 5.11 to test right now, but I tried it on 5.15.7 and it worked fine. So it may have been a bug in that version.

Comment: Yes I did - typo, sorry, edited question, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! It may as well be a bug. Does QApplication still change global style on 5.15?

Comment: I saw your yellow rectangle whether I used QApplication or QGuiApplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with 5.15.7 and was able to see the yellow rectangle whether I used QApplication or QGuiApplication. So it may be a bug in version 5.11.